# typedef с константой

Tags: c, типы-данных

Почему `const pA` это `A *const`, хотя я ожидал увидеть `const A*`?

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t i[4];
} A, *pA;

class B {
public:
    uint64_t i[2];
};

void f(pA aa) {
    std::cout << std::hex << aa->i[0] << " "
                          << aa->i[1] << " "
                          << aa->i[2] << " "
                          << aa->i[3] << std::endl;
}
void ff(const std::vector<B> &v) {
    f(const_cast<pA>(reinterpret_cast<const A *>(v.data())));
//    f(const_cast<pA>(reinterpret_cast<const pA>(v.data())));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<B> vB;
    vB.push_back({1, 1});
    ff(vB);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что так устроены языки С и С++ с самого начала времен. А почему вы вдруг  "ожидали увидеть `const A*`"? Откуда вообще мог возникнуть такой вопрос?

Comment: @AnT ожидал увидеть `const A*` потому что написал `const pA` а не `pA const`

Comment: И что? Почему вы ожидаете, что от порядка что-то будет зависеть? `typedef` имена не являются текстовыми подстановками. Не надо их рассматривать, как текстовые подстановки. Хотите текстовую подстановку - используйте макросы, а `typedef` - это совсем другое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот судите сами - что такое `pA`? Это указатель на `A`.

Тогда что такое `const pA`? Это - *константный* **`pA`**, т.е. константный *указатель на `A`*, а не указатель на константу `A`. Логично? `const` относится ко всему `pA`, как единому целому - т.е. это и есть `A* const` - указатель на `A`, константный...