# Почему данная специализация шаблона вызывает ошибку?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<typename T>  const T maxN( const T* arr, const size_t length);
template<> const char* maxN( const char** arr, const size_t length);
```

Здесь ошибка "отсутствуют экземпляры шаблон функции, соответствующие заданному типу"

При этом, если в шаблоне имя типа сделать не константой, то специализация без ошибки:

```
template<typename T>   T maxN(  T* arr, const size_t length);
template<> const char* maxN( const char** arr, const size_t length);
```

Такой код компилятор допускает...

Вопрос в том, что не так с первым вариантом кода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вас вводят в заблуждения контринтуитивные правила для описания типов в С/C++. В общем случае они определяются спиральным правилом, которое обычно вырождается в чтение справа налево. При этом квалификаторы `const` и `volatile` применяются к тому, что стоит слева от них, за исключением ситуации, когда слева от них ничего нет. Соответственно попытка простой замены `T` на `char *` в записи `const T` не приведет к жалаемому результату, так как `const char *` будет группироваться как `(const char) *` (указатель на константный char), а не как `const (char *)` (константный указатель на char).

Если аккуратно расписать исходный шаблон, всегда оставляя `const` справа, то такую замену можно будет провести без проблем:

```
template<typename T> T      const maxN( T      const * arr, size_t const length);
template<          > char * const maxN( char * const * arr, size_t const length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что посмотрите, к чему относится `const`. У вас в первом шаблоне `arr` - указатель на константный `T`, а в специализации - указатель на указатель на константный `char`, а не на константный `char*`...

Смотрите - вот такой код вполне проходит:

```
template<typename T>  const T maxN( const T* arr, const size_t length);
typedef char * pchar;
template<> const pchar maxN( const pchar* arr, const size_t length);
```

Answer (score 3):

В первом варианте вы делаете специализацию главного шаблона для `T == char *`. Если аккуратно подставить `char *` вместо `T`, то получится

```
template<typename T>  const T maxN( const T* arr, const size_t length);
template<> char* const maxN( char* const* arr, const size_t length);
```

Это будет корректной специализацией для первого варианта.

У вас же в первом варианте константность в специализации "уехала" совсем не туда.

Имена типовых шаблонных параметров ведут себя так же, как typedef-имена. Вы, похоже, находитесь в плену того же самого заблуждения, которое часто встречается с `typedef` и `const`

[typedef с константой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1016321/typedef-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Во втором варианты вы "решили" проблему неправильной расстановки константности методом "лучшее лекарство от перхоти - гильотина", то есть убрав квалификатор `const` вообще

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть:

```
const char *p = "old_array\n"; //указатель на константный символ
```

То указатель `p` записывает адрес массива, символы которых нельзя модифицировать(константные). Но зато этот указатель не константный, и можно туда записать адрес другого массива:

```
p = "new array\n";
```

Теперь он указывает  на другой массив.  Ваш шаблон запрещает делать это(он говорит, что  вы можете инстанцировать так, что  обьект типа должен быть константным, а значит, если передаете указатель, то его значение нельзя менять, он всегда укажет на тот же массив или обьект), если передать в функцию этот указаель. Однако ваша специализация разрешает, потому что указатели не константные(константные лишь массивы(обьекты), и потому сигнатуры отличаются. Второй вариант не требует константного указателья...